# Put title for plot

Tags: python

I have the code below and I want to put a title how can I do that. the original title is "Principal component plot" so I want to change to another.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_credit
from yellowbrick.features import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Program extracting first column
text = data.iloc[:,0]
lable = data.iloc[:,1]

vecot_tfidf = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
en_vec = vecot_tfidf.fit_transform(text)
fe = en_vec.toarray()

visualizer = PCA(scale=False, colors=['red','blue','green']) 
visualizer.fit_transform(fe, lable)
visualizer.show()
```

Comment: have tried `plt.title()`?

Comment: I tried but still same

Answer (score 0):

The class PCA is configured with a default title "Principal Component Plot" and hence, setting title when instantiating will not work. So we extend the class and configure it for accepting title on instantiation.
The *show()* method finalizes the drawing (adding titles, axes labels, etc) and then renders the image. And *finalize()* is the function which prepares the figure for rendering, adding final touches such as legends, titles, axis labels, etc. So you will have to create a PCA means defining a class that extends PCA or one of its subclasses, then implementing several of the methods.

```
from yellowbrick.features import PCA

class myPCA(PCA):
    def __init__(self, ax=None, **kwargs):
        super(myPCA, self).__init__(ax, **kwargs)
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.draw(X)
        return self
    def draw(self, X):
        self.ax.plt(X)
        return self.ax
    def finalize(self):
        self.set_title()

#intantiating myPCA works with title
visualizer = myPCA(scale=False, colors=['red','blue','green'],title = "My title") 

#intantiating PCA will not work with title. You can uncomment following line and check
#visualizer = PCA(scale=False, colors=['red','blue','green'],title = "My title") 

visualizer.show()
```

I hope this works!